# how to logon to a website with google-apps-script

Tags: authentication, cookies, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I'm attempting to logon to a website with Google Apps Script and I wrote a function to do this.  However I received an error message that said cookies need to be enable.  I actually don't understand what the issue is.

I'm attempting to logon to a website with Google Apps Script.
I read the following solution, and then wrote the logon function below.

[How to use UrlFetchApp with credentials? Google Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546255/how-to-use-urlfetchapp-with-credentials-google-scripts%3E)

I do have cookies enabled in my browser, so could someone please clarify what this message means and how can I fix it.

```
function logon() {
    var myurl = "https://www.someurl.com";
    var user = "name";
    var password = "########"; 
    var options = {};
    options.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " +   Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + password) };
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(myurl, options);
    var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response.getContentText());
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
}
```

## The result was a dialog message that said:

```
  In order to use this page, your browser needs to accept cookies from www.someurl.com
```

## Please enable cookies in your browser preferences and reload this page.

Based on [UrlFetchApp not connecting to public URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660031/urlfetchapp-not-connecting-to-public-url),
I revised my code to the following. However, it still results in the same error message.

```
function fetchUrlWithCookie() {
  var url = "https://www.someurl/login";
  var user = "name";
  var password = "#####"; 
  var options = {muteHttpExceptions: true,
                 followRedirects: false};
  options.headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ":" + password) };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie']; 
  var opt2 = {muteHttpExceptions: true,
                  "headers":
                      {Cookie: cookie}
             };
  var response2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.someurl/app/v4/dashboard",opt2);
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response2.getContentText());
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,"demo");
  Logger.log(response2.getContentText());
}
```

/*
      In order to use this page, your browser needs to accept cookies from www.someurl.com

```
  Please enable cookies in your browser preferences and reload this page.
```

*/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UrlFetchApp not connecting to public URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660031/urlfetchapp-not-connecting-to-public-url)